# Why is running a slice from an array taking extra time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

```
def is_prime(n, req):
    for i in req[1:]:
        if i*i>n:
            break
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True

def find_primes(n):
    if n<3:
        return 0
    req = [2]
    for x in range(3,n,2):
        if is_prime(x, req):
            req.append(x)
            print(req)
    return req
  # Fill this in.

print(find_primes(499979))
```

This code is taking much more time than

```
def is_prime(n, req):
    for i in req:
        if i*i>n:
            break
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True

def find_primes(n):
    if n<3:
        return 0
    req = [2]
    for x in range(3,n,2):
        if is_prime(x, req):
            req.append(x)
            print(req)
    return req
  # Fill this in.

print(find_primes(499979))
```

Take a loot at "is-prime" function within which the array of "req" in for loop in both codes.
This code is to find prime numbers. But why is the 2nd executing within time limits while the first one doesn't? The first should be able to run slightly faster since we are skipping the first element but why it isn't?
[image: First Code execution]

[image: 2nd code execution]

Comment: How much slower is it?

Comment: I haven't check it but it is exceeding time limit in leeetcode.

Answer (score 2):

Skipping one element's worth of work doesn't save time if it means doing copy work for the other `n - 1` elements. `req[1:]` is making a brand new `list` that omits the first element, and for large enough `req`, the cost will significantly outweigh the fixed cost of testing one extra value.

It's probably not worth skipping that element, but if you want to do so without per-item overhead, you can do:

```
def is_prime(n, req):
    req = iter(req)  # Convert to iterator
    next(req, None)  # Skip first element, if any
    for i in req:    # Iterate remainder with no additional overhead
    # Remainder of function unmodified
```

You could use `itertools.islice` to achieve a similar effect with fixed memory overhead:

```
def is_prime(n, req):
    for i in itertools.islice(req, 1, None):    # Iterate all but first element
    # Remainder of function unmodified
```

but this *would* have a small amount of per-element overhead, as iteration would always be passing through the `islice` object to get each underlying element.

Comment: Perhaps the best way to "skip" it would be to just not include it in the list at all until *after* finding the odd primes.

Comment: @HeapOverflow: True. For this specific case, without major algorithmic changes (like using a proper Sieve of Eratosthenes) that's the correct solution; explicitly consuming from an iterator is more general, but not needed here.